# font face style only works in header

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have problem with new fonts in my web site.
I do copy new fonts in folder and make a CSS.

`@font-face {`

`font-family: 'PT Sans Bold Narrow';`

`font-style: normal;`

`src: local('PTSANSBOLDNARROW'), url(font/PTSANSBOLDNARROW.woff) format('woff');}`

This code works only when it is inserted directly in the header of the web page.

When I add this code in CSS file, all things in CSS works except font-face.

Can anyone guide me what could be the mistake.

Comment: is your css file at the same place as your web page .html ?

Comment: To rephrase caramba's comment, are you sure the relative paths still point to the right place? Have you used firebug or other developer tool to see what is (or isn't) downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Wrong path url...

`url(../font/ptsansbold.woff)`

Thanks.

Comment: For future, You can use chrome inspector. Just Press F12 and in network tab look if any of the file is missing. You will also be shown the errors in the bottom right corner of the same.